# How can I format a date in a different time zone in Velocity Template using DateTool?

Tags: java, velocity

I have a date in a timezone different than GMT and I want to convert its timezone to GMT on the Velocity template.

I dont know if one can instantiate a Calendar object or TimzeZone or Locale instance on Velocity template like

#set( $tz = java.util.TimzZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))

because if it is possible then the problem can be easily solved using toDate or format functions provided by the DateTool

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here I am answering my own question. Looks like you cannot instantiate an object unless you have passed the class inside the context of the script.  Bottom line is whatever you provide in the context will be available to the template scripts, even the tools which must be configured before hand for use in the templates.

However, I cant say for sure how the templates will behave when they are used in/with a jsp file.  My usage scenario is different where I try to run the template script programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate in velocity, but you can instantiate in java and call its functions in velocity template. Here is an example for you.

```
context.put("GMT", TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
```

Now you can use $GMT in velocity template like this.

```
date.format(format,object, locale,$GMT)
```